# how to apply jquery patch file

Tags: jquery

I googled for an issue in jQuery, and found patch file form jQuery site for that. I have downloaded it. It has jus the following 4 lines of code.

```
572c572
<           if (inst.input[0].type != 'hidden')
---
>           if (inst.input[0].type != 'hidden' && inst.input[0].disabled == false     && $(inst.input[0]).is(":visible") == true)
```

Could somebody help me to apply this fix in the existing jquery library. I tried searching for the above text in the library, but  couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to change

```
       if (inst.input[0].type != 'hidden')
```

to

```
       if (inst.input[0].type != 'hidden' && inst.input[0].disabled == false && $(inst.input[0]).is(":visible") == true)
```

in your code. Whole code you posted is called "diff" output

Comment: You can apply diffs with `patch`

Comment: Not 100% sure if you're being sarcastic or not, but the person who asked the question most likely didn't know that and it's not worth writing another answer just to say that.

Comment: @awoodland is it a jQuery method or what?

Comment: @Jose: linux.. it's about linux diff and patch

Comment: I'm really tired about all this linux stuff going on there... it's really time to start using it also for myself! :P

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but to do this you should first download a non-compressed version of the jQuery library (development), then search for this line of code

```
if (inst.input[0].type != 'hidden')
```

And replace it with this one

```
if (inst.input[0].type != 'hidden' && inst.input[0].disabled == false     && $(inst.input[0]).is(":visible") == true)
```

Then save the new patched file and you may want to compress it again using one of the many compression tools avaiable online.

Comment: be sure you downloaded the right jQuery version the patch has been created for.

Comment: inrrespective of the version, inst.input[0].type should be there.. This is also not there in the library...

Comment: It may be there for a particular jQuery version, but not for all of them necessarily. In each version the code may change just a little, or entire functions may be completely changed/added/removed.