# Attaching the patch to JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem in setting todayDate in Jquery Datepicker. While Searching on the issue I found this link

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5151

I could not understand how to attach the patch to the existing ui.

Can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

You can see more informations in this thread :
[how to apply jquery patch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176673/how-to-apply-jquery-patch-file)

you need to replace line started with "<" by line started with ">".

**Edit :**
Wrong copy / paste (damn it). I correct the link.

Comment: you placed a link which takes to this question only